# django CMS error cms_urlconfrevision on deployment

Tags: django, heroku, django-cms

I'm trying to deploy a django CMS app to PythonAnywhere or Heroku but I keep getting this error on Heroku:

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "cms_urlconfrevision" does not exist
LINE 1: ...sion"."id", "cms_urlconfrevision"."revision" FROM "cms_urlco...
```

and this error on PythonAnywhere:

```
OperationalError at /
no such table: cms_urlconfrevision
```

The app works fine on `localhost`.

I understand it's a database table missing but I have no idea how to fix it. I tried removing all the migration files and `.pyc` files and migrated again, I removed the database, I tried migration with `--fake`. Nothing seems to work.

I'm using

- django-cms==3.6.0
- Django==2.1.8

Comment: Have you tried simply running the migrations with `heroku run python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: dude i've been stuck on that for 2 days i read the heroku deployment docs way to many times and never seen such a command. that solved my problem thanks

Comment: Okay, I'll add a proper answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand it's a database table missing but I have no idea how to fix it. I tried removing all the migration files and `.pyc` files and migrated again, I removed the database, I tried migration with `--fake`. Nothing seems to work.

Migration files just define what migrations exist. They don't modify your database by themselves. There are two steps here:

1. Creating migrations with `makemigrations`. This should only be done on your development machine. By the time your code is being deployed you shouldn't have any model changes that would cause new migrations to be generated.
2. Applying migrations to your database with `migrate`. This must be done in development (to update your local database) and also in production (to update your production database).

   On Heroku, you'd run your migrations with

   ```
   heroku run python manage.py migrate
   ```

   I think this is the step you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

Hello maybe you found the solution but if the is somebody coming across that issue, it due to the database settings.

In project_name/site_name/settings.py and database settings section

Change

```
NAME: 'project.db'
```

to

```
NAME:'project_name/project.bd'
```

Answer (score 0):

in the file setting.py change

```
  'NAME': 'project.db',
```

to

```
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'project.db',
```

worked for me