# Getting really strange error when deploying a django app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, exception, django-models, heroku-cli

I tried to deploy my django application to heroku using the starter guide and the other manual that shows you to create your runtime, requirements, procfiles, installing django-heroku, etc. So I've now deployed my site but recieve the following error.[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNFuP.png) I'm unsure of why this error is showing up at all especially when it worked perfectly fine locally. I haven't followed all of the django deployment checklist yet, such as setting `DEBUG` to `False` because I'd like to ensure that it works correctly before I do. If anyone could help me, that'd be much appreceiated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: ProgrammingError relation does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980717/django-programmingerror-relation-does-not-exists)

Comment: yep! It does! Thank You! The only issue is now I'm getting other problems: like this post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330432/django-makemigrations-and-migrate-on-heroku-server-dont-create-tables, but I don't know how to ssh into a dyno, and I can't comment for clarification since I don't have 50 reps yet.

Comment: You don't exactly "ssh into a dyno" on Heroku. You can use [`heroku run bash`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run), but that spins up a new dyno with the same application slug.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of that question applies to you , but [you shouldn't have to run `makemigrations` on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56293094/354577) and doing so shouldn't generate any. Your migration files need to be generated in development and committed. Are you using SQLite? [You can't use that on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47745470/354577). You'll need to switch to a client-server database. PostgreSQL is a common choice.

Comment: There are lots of questions asking about this kind of thing. If my links don't help, keep searching. I bet you'll find something helpful. And if you don't, feel free to ask another question including a [mcve] and as much detail about your errors as you can. Please see [ask] for tips on asking effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do migration after pushing to Heroku.

**Note:** Don't use local migrations. You can use Heroku bash to connect remotely and perform migrations just like you do locally.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail how to do that?

Comment: Should I clear all of my current migrations?